# Inserting user defined number of spaces before and after string using C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, textbox, string-formatting

I am using string builder to format my string to append and prepend white spaces at the start and end of the string

here is what I have so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String Word = textBox1.Text;
   AppendPrependText(Word);
}
private void AppendPrependText (String Word)
{
   int count = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
   int WordCount = Word.Count();
   int totalChar = count + WordCount;
   string format = "{-"+totalChar+ "," +totalChar+ "}";
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   sb.AppendLine(string.Format(format, Word));
   textBox3.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

but I'm getting the error incorrect format. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: could you please specify the sample input and expected output?

Comment: Why not use `.PadLeft()` and `.PadRight()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need not to use separate operation for formatting the string, you can use `.AppendFormat()` method of the `StringBuilder Class`. Here is a sample code for you:

```
StringBuilder sbAppendFormat = new StringBuilder();
int numberOfSpaces=0;
if(int.TryParse(textBo2.Text, out numberOfSpaces))
{
    string whiteSpaceSequence= new string(' ',numberOfSpaces);
    sbAppendFormat.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{0}", whiteSpaceSequence, "This is your String");
}
textBox3.Text = sbAppendFormat.ToString();
```

Note:- Assume that you need to add Some white spaces(let it be `5`) before and after the specific word.

Comment: Glad to hear that, and happy to help you

Comment: Awesome. :) This is beautiful and simple.

Comment: simplified: sbAppendFormat.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{0}", whiteSpaceSequence, "This is your String");

Comment: @matk: yep, nice suggestion

Answer (score 3):

There's two issues here.  The first is that you're correctly using a `StringBuilder` to format a string which reduces the overhead caused by concatenation but you're *also* performing extra concatenation on that `format` local variable.

The second issue is that your format string is wrong: it doesn't include the argument index.  Your method expects a single word, so that index should be zero before the padding instruction.

Fortunately, you could skip past the concatenation of the format string and simply append your user-defined space (or whatever character) to the fresh instance of the `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 3):

Your code has some errors:

`Format Exception` will be thrown by this line for sure:

```
sb.AppendLine(string.Format(format, Word));
```

Your current format doesn't contain any `{0}` in which the `Word` value should be replaced.

```
//you should put here somewhere {0} in the format or remove the Word for string.Format
//for an example
string format = "{-" + totalChar + "," + totalChar + "}{0}";
```

Also this line is possible `Format Exception` if the `textBox2.Text` is for an example *a11*:

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
```

You need to use `int.TryParse`

```
int count = 0;
int.TryParse(textBo2.Text, out count);
```

Answer (score 3):

What seems to be the issue is

```
string format = "{-"+totalChar+ "," +totalChar+ "}";
```

Letz say if totalChar = 10; than

```
format = "{-10,10}"
```

which is not a valid format whereas it should be

```
{0,10}{1,10}
```

and thus your string would look like

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,10}{1,10}", "Mohit",""));
```

The third argument was intentionally left blank so that nothing would be printed after the word. but you will have 10 spaces.

But I would recommend you to use [`String.PadRight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s.aspx) and [`String.PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

An example to demostrate your task using PadLeft and PadRight

```
int count = 5;
string st = "mohit ";
int WordCount = st.Count();
int totalChar = count + WordCount;

st = st.PadRight(totalChar, ' ');
st = st.PadLeft(totalChar + count, ' ');
Console.WriteLine(st);
```

Answer (score 3):

For simple adding spaces or chars, in front and/or back, Padding will work fine.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    int amount;
    int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out amount);

    var str = textBox1.Text.PadLeft(amount + textBox1.TextLength);
    str = str.PadRight(amount + str.Length);

    textBox3.Text = str;
}
```

Then you can choose a spacer *(paddingChar)* also later if needed/wanted

```
var str = textBox1.Text.PadLeft(amount + textBox1.TextLength, '>');
str = str.PadRight(amount + str.Length, '<');
```

Additionally with an extra method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    textBox3.Text = Format(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
}

private string Format(string word, string spaces)
{
    int amount;
    int.TryParse(spaces, out amount);

    var str = word.PadLeft(amount + word.Length);
    str = str.PadRight(amount + str.Length);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not use `StringBuilder`, I returned a `String` from `AppendPrependText`. The if statement checks for invalid integer input in textBox2, if its invalid return the original string. If it is a valid integer, create a `padString` with `count` number of spaces then return the original string sandwiched between two of the `padStrings`.

**EDIT:** added check for negative numbers by adding AND `count > 0` to the if statement.

```
private String AppendPrependText(String Word)
{
  int count = 0;
  if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out count) && count > 0)
  {
    String padString = "".PadLeft(count, ' ');
    return padString + Word.ToString() + padString;
  }
  else
  {
    return Word;
  }
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  String Word = textBox1.Text;
  textBox3.Text = ">" + AppendPrependText(Word) + "<";
}
```